# Embed feed ObjectProperties: image is not visible in Yammer site feed page

Tags: yammer

I am using objectProperties for image to be visible in yammer feed of page. But it is not showing in yammer site feed page.  Image url I am specifiying from SharePoint site collection image library(https://XX.sharepoint.com/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif). However it is working fine if I give some internet accessed image (e.g. www.google.com/images/123.gif).

Also If I click on “goto page” link in that feed there same image is visible. Please note I am already logged in to SharePoint site with another tab.

objectProperties: {
type: "page",
title: pageTitle,
url: pageUrl,
image: "https://XX.sharepoint.com/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif"
}

@Yammer-team: I think embed.ly is interrupting in home page feed. can you please check and confirm. Thanks.

Comment: I got the answer from Yammer documentation that currently yammer is supporting image url only accessible from publicly accessible content. https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/#og-schema

Comment: We use embed.ly and hence it needs to be available on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Yammer documentation that currently yammer is supporting image url only accessible from publicly accessible content. https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/#og-schema

one more comment from Myo Thein that - "We use embed.ly and hence it needs to be available on the internet."